# How can i access the data inside the Datetime Object?

Tags: php

I am trying to access the data inside the Datetime object

```
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2020-03-26 19:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => "Test/test )
```

I want to get the `date` i am trying to get it using this code `$date_time->date` but i am having an error of `Cannot use object of type DateTime as array`

I know this is just a simple problem, but i already have no idea on how can i access the data from it.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the php manual to look for a suitable function

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

You can use `format` function as `$date_time->format('Y-m-d')`

The format the date string using php predefined characters https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Thank you sir, i already found the answer. ```$date_time->format('m-d-Y H:i:s')``` thanks sir.